# Rounding problems on Zoho Books API (JS)

Tags: javascript, zoho, zohobooks

I am currently working with ZohoBooks API with JavaScript, and I have some problems, when I try to add a bill with a post request.

```
line_items: [
   {
      account_id: '8057xxxxxxxxxxx',
      rate: 577.09,
      tax_id: '8057xxxxxxxxxxx'
   }
],
taxes: [ { tax_id: '8057xxxxxxxxxxx', tax_amount: 20 } ]
```

The total including tax is not equal to what I would like to have.
I have an amount at `577.09` excluding tax and tax at `20%`. I should get `692.50` in total including tax.

> 577.09*(20/100) = 115.418
>
> 577.09+115.418 = 692.508

I would like to round the result to `692.50` and not `692.51` as the tool does.
Is there a way to specify on the bill POST, an amount including VAT directly when adding?

This is the result that I obtain.
[image: Example]

Comment: Can't you use the adjustment field in the bill?